# Rewrite PHP file names to cgi with htaccess and deny access to php files

Tags: php, .htaccess

I rewrite the file name of php files with below htaccess code :

```
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.html

AddType application/x-httpd-php .cgi
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.cgi $1\.php
```

***What I want to do :*** can I restrict access to php files too ? for example if visitor want to see `page.php` get the 404 error and when want to see `main.cgi` page can see the page without error , is it possible ?
if I can't do this with just htaccess , what's the best solution ?

Comment: Do your Query_String checks end up doing anything? It appears that _only_ if one of them fires _and_ the Request_Filename is not a file or directory, will the RewriteRule kick in. Are you missing a RewriteRule for the Query_String checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve what you want by having the php files outside of your public folder, than have your index.php file include them

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
```

and in index.php something like

```
$validFiles = array('page', 'about', 'gallery');

$requestedFile = str_replace('.cgi', '', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');

if(in_array($requestedFile, $validFiles ))
{
    // ../ goes into the parent folder, and code is a sibling of your public folder
    include '../code/'.$requestedFile.'.php';
}
else
{
    // file not found stuff or index here
}
```

Though I would question why you need to use the .cgi extension at all, is that something to do with your host, or a legacy requirement? because with htaccess you can have clean urls like

mydomain.com/products/widget/

Comment: Thanks CodeMonkey , I want to have clean URLS and change php original php files .